# Pagerank update upon vertex removal

Tags: graph-algorithms, markov-chains, streaming-algorithms, probabilistic-computation

Assume we have computed the [Pagerank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank) of the vertices of a given graph. Then, remove a vertex from this graph, with all its edges.

**How to efficiently compute the Pagerank of remaining vertices in the new graph?**

**Would it help to know that we remove the vertex with highest Pagerank?**

I see work on edge removals in the literature, but updating after vertex removal may be faster than updating after removal of each of its edges, in particular in the the highest-Pagerank removal case.